# Flask BuildError, could not build url for endpoint

Tags: python, flask

I have the following `url_for`

```py
url_for('posts.post_images', filename=post.img, size=710)
```

and the route's method

```py
@posts.route('/posts/images/<path:filename>/<int:size>')
def post_images(filename, size):
    if size:
        return ImageProcessingService.get_image_by_size(filename, size)
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'src/posts/images')
    return send_from_directory(path, filename)
```

and console asks me  `Did you forget to specify values ['size']`
I justs don't get it, both values are in the `url_for` call, in the route's decorator and in the method's signature. Any ideas?

the exact error:
`werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'posts.post_images' with values ['filename']. Did you forget to specify values ['size']?`

Comment: Seems like url_for function is correct. Did you restart the server? and in which file you mentioned this url_for function? And what is post.img?.

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan thanks for your answer. `post.img` is an image's fiename. Yes, of course i restarted the server. I mentioned the url_for function in a template where i'm looping all posts